# Adding a query to SQL Server Import and Export Wizard

Tags: sql, excel, import, ssis, ssms

I am wanting to update the inv_mast table with an excel spreadsheet. I was able to successfully do this by importing the data as a table and then running the query afterwards and then dropping the table. I am wanting to try and add it to the SSIS package, so I do everything in one step. The excel sheet has ItemID and a Price column to update inv_mast that also has the same columns.

But I am getting this error when I use the code that I use to already complete the process.

```
The statement could not be parsed.
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'ExcelSheet.price2
FROM
P21PLAY.dbo.inv_mast IM
INNER JOIN
Sheet1$ ExcelSheet
ON
IM.item_id = S.item_id'. (Microsoft Office Access Database Engine)
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7apM.png)

Here is the code I have.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION 
UPDATE
P21PLAY.dbo.inv_mast
SET
P21PLAY.dbo.inv_mast.price2 = ExcelSheet.price2
FROM
P21PLAY.dbo.inv_mast IM
INNER JOIN
Sheet1$ ExcelSheet
ON 
IM.item_id = S.item_id;
DROP TABLE sheet1$
```

Comment: FYI [3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/) and should be avoided. You are far better off aliasing your objects in the `FROM` and using those to qualify your columns. This avoids the use of a feature that will be deprecated and possibly removed in a future version, and makes your code much more succinct and readable.

Comment: What happens if you delimit identify `Sheet1$` and switch to aliasing in both the `UPDATE` and `SET` clause? (`[Sheet1$]` and `UPDATE IM SET IM.price2` respectively.)

Comment: I did as you suggested and this is the outcome. 

'The statement could not be parsed
IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005).(System.Data)

'UPDATE IM
SET IM.price2 = ES.price2
FROM P21PLAY.dbo.inv_mast IM
INNER JOIN Sheet1$ ES ON IM.item_id = ES.item_id;
DROP TABLE sheet1$'

Comment: Wait, are you trying to run that query against an Excel spreadsheet with ACE? That won't work; ACE has no context of the data in your database. If you want to do that, you'll need to use a dataflow task in SSIS, use the sheet as one source, the table as another, and then perform a lookup transformation.

Comment: My goal is to update pricing using an excel spreadsheet. I can do it by importing the excel spreadsheet into the database and then updating the prices and then dropping the table that was created when I imported the excel spreadsheet. But I feel like there is an easier way to do this.

I am not sure what ACE is.

Comment: ACE is the driver you are, presumably, using to connect to the Excel file; that or it's a Excel 2003 file and you're using JET (I hope not).

Comment: I am not sure how to check that if I am using that driver or not, I am using the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard in SSMS. For this to work, I have to select excel version: Microsoft Excel 2007-2010 in the drop down menu.